# Non-ascii remote file names incorrectly shown in Emacs dired

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, remote-access, tramp, dired

Dired seems unable to correctly show characters like "ç" or "í" in filenames when listing remote directories (e.g. /scpc:myhost:/home/myuser). It displays "??" for every non-ascii character. How can I fix this? Is this a dired limitation?

The worst thing is that many dired-based commands doesn't work with those files (e.g. file renaming).

On the contrary, ibuffer, eshell, and other commands work fine with any remote filename (and display them properly).

The problem arises for remote ext3 and ext4 filesystems in different machines, haven't tried other filesystems. I've found this problem in both Emacs versions I have installed: 24.1.50.1 and 23.3. I've also tried with dired+, same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(setq tramp-remote-process-environment ())
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8" 'append)
```

For more information about Tramp problems with UTF-8 - [see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002123/emacs-diredtramp-wrong-filenames-with-utf8/15063599)