# Emacs dired+tramp, wrong filenames with UTF8

Tags: emacs, encoding, utf-8, dired, tramp

When using tramp+dired first I got this:
[image: bad utf8 symbols]

And I thought I solved it by these lines:

```
(setq tramp-remote-process-environment ())
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8" 'append)
```

But now something wrong happens:
[image: bad filename, dirname length]

also wasn't helpful:  "LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8"

Now Dired gets wrong filename(dirname) length. You can see this for dir including modification date (also blue).

And this happens for arbitrary filenames (not all of them).
So I cant manipulate files when Dired gets their incorrect names.
Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported this bug and the author fixed it. Just great!
Install Tramp from sources. Use 2.2.7-pre or higher.

[Obtain tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Obtaining-Tramp)
[Installation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Installation)

```
cd ~/src
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/tramp.git
# also see INSTALL file in dir
cd tramp
autoconf
./configure --with-contrib
make
make install
```